# Error upgrading from 18.04 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04 and I'm getting a set of errors that I'm not sure how to resolve :

```
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:13741): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:43.927: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:13741): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:43.927: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:13741): GLib-ERROR **: 03:30:43.927: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:14683): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:50.679: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:14683): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:50.679: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:14683): GLib-ERROR **: 03:30:50.679: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease               
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

(appstreamcli:15643): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:57.135: g_variant_builder_end: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->uniform_item_types || GVSB(builder)->prev_item_type != NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (GVSB(builder)->type)' failed

(appstreamcli:15643): GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:30:57.135: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:15643): GLib-ERROR **: 03:30:57.135: g_variant_new_parsed: 11-13:invalid GVariant format string
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Error during update
```

I was undertaking sudo do-release-upgrade when I received this error. Based on the bug fix for this it states that I need to be on 0.12.0-3, and mine is already on this version :

```
dpkg -l appstream libappstream4
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-===================================================================================================
ii  appstream                                       0.12.0-3                     amd64                        Software component metadata management
ii  libappstream4:amd64                             0.12.0-3                     amd64                        Library to access AppStream services
```

Comment: 18.04 to 19.04 is not a tested, supported upgrade path. 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04 *is* a tested and supported upgrade path.

Comment: You have *cosmic* in apt's output. Do you really have running 18.04 LTS (bionic beaver)? You mean 18.10 to 19.04 upgrade, are not you?

Comment: @tatsu I have upgraded many machines without problem. Upgrades do work...if you do them properly.

Comment: @tatsu having helped run some 18.10 to 19.04 QA-Testing upgrades, I know they work and have run it many times (on real hardware).

Comment: @guiverc that would be disregarding the ton of askubuntu questions on upgrades to 19.04 failing